# Weird Behaviour with QScrollArea in PyQt5 (not scrolling)

Tags: python, qt, matplotlib, pyqt5, qscrollarea

I am trying to create a scrollable report to show a couple of Matplotlib Figures and QTableView tables. I create the GUI layout in Qt Designer for which the `scrollArea` widget is generated with:

```
self.scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self.centralwidget)
self.scrollArea.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 487))
self.scrollArea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
self.scrollArea.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
self.scrollArea.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QtWidgets.QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustToContents)
self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
self.scrollArea.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
self.scrollArea.setObjectName("scrollArea")
self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = QtWidgets.QWidget()
self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(8, 0, 756, 485))
self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents")
self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
self.main_v_layout.addWidget(self.scrollArea)
```

I add the Matplotlib Figure to a `QVBoxLayout` and set it as the `scrollArea` widget:

```
# Setup Widgets
self.plot_widget = myCanvas()  # Matplotlib Figure 
self.widget = qtw.QWidget()
self.scroll_widget = qtw.QVBoxLayout()
self.scroll_widget.addWidget(self.plot_widget)  # Add Matplotlib Figure
self.widget.setLayout(self.scroll_widget)
self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.widget)
# self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setLayout(self.scroll_widget)
```

This gives the output shown in the image below:

[image: Layout with figure in scroll area]

I then proceed to add some `QTableView`'s to the `self.scroll_widget` like so:

```
  self.model = MyTableModel(data)
  self.view = qtw.QTableView()
  self.view.setModel(self.model)
  self.view.show()
  self.scroll_widget.addWidget(self.view)
```

Which resizes my Matplotlib graph without adding a scroll bar:
[image: resized graph]

If I keep adding `QTableView`'s to the `QVBoxLayout` eventually the Matplotlib Figure disappears and THEN the scroll bar appears:
[image]

What is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Upon finding this [link](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/14160), I have realised the issue is no minimum size being specified to the `FigureCanvas` of the Matplotlib Figure. Adding the last line to my custom `FigureCanvas` class solved things:

```
class myCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self): 
        self.fig = Figure()  
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, self.fig)
        FigureCanvas.setMinimumSize(self, self.size())
```

Hope this helps someone in the future!